# How to make a group and only show the smaller number of a cell

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2019

I have a spreed sheet called went to. It has name of places and people, as well as a cell that shows how many months ago someone went there.
I am trying to make a list with the name of everyone and the places they went to. But I only want to show the last time they went to such a place.

I try two functions, they are "AGGREGATE" and "MINIFS"

The function AGGREGATE for was:

=AGGREGATE(15;3;(A:A=A2)*(G:G);2)

The function MINIFS for was

=MINIFS($G$2:$G$100;A2:A100;A2)
I also try like this
The function MINIFS for was

=MINIFS($G$2:$G$100;A2:A100;A2=A2)
But it only show me zeros

[image]

Am I using the wrong functions or I am using the right function wrong?

I just try funtion AGGREGATE like this:

=AGGREGATE(5;4;went_to!A2=spreadsheet1!A2;went_to!E2)

But is shows me "#VALOR!"

This is the spreedSheet went_to
[image]

Here is an exemplo of what I want:
[image]

A person went to a place mutiples time. I want to show only the last time that the person went to that place.

[image]

"I just thought of a better metaphor for what I want. My intention is to create a spreedsheet that shows the last place an inspector went to a determined place. So I can make a list of every place that he still can go (the time difference in months exist because the condition to he be abe to go to a place is that he/she can't have gone there in the last 4 months)
But I am not sure which funtion or functions should I used to make it happen. "

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you would expect - to me your requirement is not clear compared to the functions you propose.

Comment: I will be making an example right now! 
But to summarize:
I want to use the data above to make an spreedsheet that has the name of a person, the place and the time difference (the smaller difference, or be the last time that someone went there)

Comment: I manage to do it with microsoft 365 using function filter, but my company doesn't have it and therefore I cannot use the function filter.

Comment: I just thought of a better metaphor for what I want. My intention is to create a spreedsheet that shows the last place an inspector went to a determined place. So I can make a list of every place that he still can go (the time difference in months exist because the condition to he be abe to go to a place is that he/she can't have gone there in the last 4 months)
But I am not sure which funtion or functions should I used to make it happen.